# reactjs Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < with django

Tags: django, reactjs

[image]

I am trying to deploy my django-react in azure vm.

when i am using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

it is working fine.

but,
when i am using .

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 settings.wsgi
```

This is is showing above error in console.

Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the static files are not being loaded. `gunicorn` does not serve static contents.

So, you can use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve these static contents. You can install it via `pip install whitenoise`. Then you can enable it like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

More information can be found in [their documentation regarding using whitenoise on django](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html).

Alternatively, you can use reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache or Varnish to serve static contents as well.